# How I can set via Registry the color of this screen in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-registry, colors, desktop-customization

In Windows 8.1, how I can set the color of this Screen to Black color?

[image]

I know that the color ID for the `Black` color is `0` 'cause I did the trick with `Windows 8` using `Windows System Image Manager` included in the `ADK` package to make an unatended Windows installation setting the default colorization values, but this parameter doesn't worked when I did an unatended installation for `Windows 8.1`, so I would like to change the colorization manually from the Registry using `Regedit` (I need to automate this change for the unatended installation).

Comment: The person who answered to suggest me to use Start Screen Color Tuner for Windows 8.1, please don't delete your answer, was usefull, I will mark your answer as accepted 'cause I've monitored the values that the program changes so I've really solved the issue with your solution.

Comment: I've rolled back you edit. If you have a solution to your problem please don't edit it into your question. Instead, post it as an answer (you're allowed to answer your own questions).  Also, the answer that the user deleted (their own) was insufficient for SU standard anyway and most likely would have been deleted by voters/mods.

Comment: It's ok, I just wanted to give reputation to the person who helped me to solve the problem, and not mark my own answer, thanks for comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone is interested to, the registry values to set the start-screen to black are these:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent]
"StartColor"=dword:ff1c1c1c

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent]
"DefaultStartColor"=dword:ff1c1c1c
```